# waiting Thread never wakes up

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a ThreadManager with two Threads. One for gui-relevant requests and one for measurement-relevant requests. The are both running and checking their queue of requests, if there is any, they are processing the request. One can add requests at any time, using the static `ThreadManager.addGuiRequest(eGuiRequest)` and `ThreadManager.addMeasRequest(eMeasRequest)` methods. Now both of those need to be initialized which is done by adding a `INIT` request to the corresponding queue. But the initialization of the measurement is depending on the fact that the gui is already initialized. I tried to solve this using `wait()/notify()`, but I can not get it working.

Here is a SSCCE. At startup, both queues have a INIT request added and are then started. The measurement initialization detects that the gui is not yet initialized and perfomrs a `wait()`. The gui initializes (simulated by sleeping for 5s). This all works fine.

After the gui initialized, it tries to wake up the measurement thread, but the measurement thread does not wake up... I based my `wait()/notify()` code on [this article](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html). What is going wrong here?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ThreadManager {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadManager();
        ThreadManager.addMeasRequest(eMeasRequest.OTHER_STUFF);
    }

    public enum eGuiRequest { INIT, OTHER_STUFF; }
    public enum eMeasRequest { INIT, OTHER_STUFF; }

    private static LinkedList<eGuiRequest> guiQueue = new LinkedList<eGuiRequest>();
    private static LinkedList<eMeasRequest> measQueue = new LinkedList<eMeasRequest>();
    private static Thread guiThread, measThread;
    protected boolean initialized = false;

    public ThreadManager() {
        final int waitMs = 200;    
        guiThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (guiQueue.isEmpty()) sleepMs(waitMs);
                        else {
                            eGuiRequest req = guiQueue.getFirst();
                            processGuiRequest(req);
                            guiQueue.removeFirst();
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
                }
            }

            private void processGuiRequest(eGuiRequest req) {
                System.out.println("T: " + "Processing Gui request: " + req);
                switch (req) {
                case INIT:
                    // do some initializiation here - replaced by a wait:
                    sleepMs(5000);
                    System.out.println("I: " + "guiThread finished, waking up measThread");
                    synchronized (measThread) {
                        initialized = true;
                        measThread.notify();
                    }
                    break;
                case OTHER_STUFF:
                    // do other stuff
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        measThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (measQueue.isEmpty()) sleepMs(waitMs);
                        else {
                            eMeasRequest req = measQueue.getFirst();
                            processMeasurementRequest(req);
                            measQueue.removeFirst();
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
                }
            }

            private void processMeasurementRequest(eMeasRequest req) {
                if (req == eMeasRequest.INIT) { // if init, wait until GUI is initialized
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (!initialized) {
                            System.out.println("I: " + "measThread waits for guiThread to finish initializiation");
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (Exception e) {}
                            System.out.println("I: " + "measThread awakes");
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("T: " + "Processing Measurement request: " + req);
                // process request here:
                sleepMs(5000);
            }
        });

        addGuiRequest(eGuiRequest.INIT);
        addMeasRequest(eMeasRequest.INIT);

        guiThread.start();
        measThread.start();
    }

    public static void sleepMs(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException ee) {}
    }

    public static void addGuiRequest(eGuiRequest req) {
        guiQueue.add(req);
    }

    public static void addMeasRequest(eMeasRequest req) {
        measQueue.add(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUI thread calls `notify()` on `measThread` (of type Thread), and the `processMeasurementRequest()` method calls `wait()` on `this`, which is the Runnable instance used by `measThread`.

I would advise using a specific object, shared by both threads to wait and notify:

```
private static final Object GUI_INITIALIZATION_MONITOR = new Object();
```

Also, instead of using a LinkedList and sleeping an aritrary time between requests, I would use a BlockingQueue: this would allow the consuming thread to handle a request as soon as there is one, and would avoid unnecessary wakeups from the sleeping state.

Also, instead of the low-level wait/notify, you could use a CountDownLatch initialized to 1. The GUI thread would `countDown()` the latch when it's initialized, and the mesurement thread would `await()` the latch until the GUI thread has called `countDown()`. This would delegate complex synchronization and notification stuff to a more high-level, well-tested object.

Comment: Very good, that did it. So I guess the `synchronized` can also be done on that shared object (`synchronized (GUI_INITIALIZATION_MONITOR) { initialized = true; GUI_INITIALIZATION_MONITOR.notify(); }`, right?

Comment: it MUST be done on this monitor. You must hold the monitor of an object to be able to call wait() and notify() on it.

Comment: I see. Regarding your edit: I am very new to the whole multithreading stuff, so I went with the most basic approach, because I was very confused with the whole concurrency stuff. ^^ But I guess I should read into that, because everyone says it's much better than `wait()/notify()`... Also thanks for the tipp with the `BlockingQueue`, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Using `LinkedBlockingQueue` now, it is much cleaner code (easier to read) and it is the better solution as well. I wish I could give more than one upvote. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you call `notify()` on `measThread`, but `wait()` is called on an anonymous class. The easiest way to fix this is to create a special object for synchronization. For example, you create a field:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
```

Then you write synchronized blocks using this object and call its methods like this:

```
synchronized (LOCK) {
    while (!initialized) LOCK.wait();
}
```

Also I have to say that this piece of code doesn't use any synchronization at all for the fields accessed from different threads, which means that it can break at any time. Both queues are accessed outside the threads created by you, this means that you should either access them with a lock held all the time, or you can make them thread safe by using a built-in synchronized list:

```
quiQueue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<eGuiRequest>());
```

`initialized` is accessed from synchronized blocks, but right now they synchronize on different locks (I have described this problem at the start of my answer). If you fix this problem, `initialized` will also be working as it should.

Comment: Thanks also for the hint with the synchronized list. @JBNizet suggested using `BlockingQueue` and I guess those are synchronized anyway, so that will be taken care of.

Comment: Also, isn't a line like `initialized = true;` atomic and should therefore not have a problem with synchronization?

Comment: @brimborium Actually, if I were to code this, I would probably create two executors by calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and wouldn't use any queues at all. Only I don't really know if you are trying to understand how `notify()` and `wait()` work or simply doing some task, that's why I answered the question directly.

Comment: @brimborium It is a single operation. But the problem is that there is no guarantee that the other threads see that you've made some changes to the field, so there is still a problem.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, it's a bit of both. I was interested in the `wait()/notify()` (which is working now), but I am also interested in any form of critique and/or suggestion on how to do this best, so thanks for mentioning `Executors`, I will look into that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not sent init request to measurment at startup. Sent it from processGuiRequest() after execution of init gui request. Then no wait/notify stuff is needed.

Comment: That is a very good idea. I just wanted to know how that `wait()/notify()` works anyway, but thanks for that input.